# HTML5 Local DataStorage Fetch Values

Tags: html

I am new to this html5.

Today, i took an example from the below url:
http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/

You can check the demo here.
http://blog.darkcrimson.com/samples/localdb/

Now  my question:
Is it possible to fetch all the values entered in the text box and dropdown.

In other words, if i use the above url in 2 different browsers and update my preference, is it possible to fetch both the data(updated in two browsers) ?

Thanks -
Haan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Local storage is stored locally, in the browser.  If you use a different browser then you are using a different local store.

Comment: Ok, then if i am using same browser(ex:chrome) and update the preference twice or thrice, is it possible to take all the values i have updated.

Comment: @hjaffer2001 It's possible to put any data you want into local storage, but you're going to have to write code to capture the date you want stored and put it there.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, lemme give it a try. :)